# How to get different values in the same environment variable

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, powershell, environment-variables

I have two apps I want, when they will access the same environment variable but will receive different values.
It is possible?

Comment: No, any environment is like any variable, it holds 1 item. int a, can only  hold one int..Not really a c# question, this is a generic windows question

Comment: Only if you store user-scope variables with the same name and launch the apps with different credentials. Other way is to define a variable just before the app launches through powershell or batch script.

Comment: There are many environment variables in `PowerShell` which change depending on the host machine, but which ones are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate each app with a batch that sets the respective variable.

Create a text file `APP1.BAT` which sets the environment variable and then calls app1, and enter that text file as the target of the icon for app1 you click on. Do the same for app2, with its respective environment variable value in its text file.